# Nextjs 13 deletes cookies on production server

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, vps, production-environment

#### Context

I have recently migrated from vite to Nextjs `13.4.18` app directory because I wanted to use SSR. I have a backend express API with integrated Google Auth using passport which was working perfectly with vite (and client-side rendering on nextjs). Nextjs instance works fine on local machine with full login functionality (both `next dev` and `next start` envs).

#### Problem

My login functionality breaks when hosted on a nginx vps (both `next dev` and `next start` envs). Client side fetching works fine, but SSR fails to fetch. Passing cookies won't work on vps as nextjs doesn't set the cookie anyway (cookie name: `connect.sid`). A login is successful on backend, but fetching data on SSR fails.

#### Code samples

Express Cookie Settings:

```
{
    secret: 'i love pizza',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    store
}
```

`/api/auth/google` route:

```
app.get('/google', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: scopes
        prompt: 'consent',
        accessType: 'offline'
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Above works with client side

Fetching example on SSR:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
// ...
fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/me`, {
    headers: { Cookie: cookies().toString() },
    cache: "no-cache"
});
```

Fetching example on client:

```
fetch("https://api.tutorsamahesl.com/api/me", {
    credentials: "include"
});
```

Running above in frontend console will bring back `connect.sid` cookie (while authenticated) in chrome dev tools until refreshing the page.

#### Extra

Frontend and backend are hosted on separate subdomains on same vps.

Please don't hesitate to ask me for further info / runtime logs, thanks!